# IBM-cloud Watson Studio Notebook failed to load (BM PY0101EN Python Basics for Data Science)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ibm-cloud, typeerror, watson-studio

I am trying to load a notebook created by another course student for peer assessment as required by the `IBM PY0101EN Python Basics for Data Science course` Final Assignment. However, I keep getting an error message loading the notebook.

The error message reads: **TypeErrors: this metadata is undefined**, and I am the process always stops at 99% loading the notebook. I have allowed cookies and not running any other Watson studio program. I cannot finish the assignment unless I complete this.

The note is created via Notebook URL pasting the URL address submitted for peer assessment:

https://jp-tok.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/analytics/notebooks/v2/33f7a9cd-09de-411c-a081-b1c6c2c4db62/view?access_token=4c9646957be256d9d36d1a8cbef0ffef9908775ba12a730f2089a8ee37e4a63b

Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a notebook "*From URL*", the URL must return content in the [Jupyter Notebook Format](https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The URL you shared returns HTML data.

If your Watson Studio instance runs in Tokyo (seen by *jp-tok* in the URL), you can add the notebook to your project via two different ways

- use the "*Copy to project*" button in the upper right corner
- use the "*Download*" button in the upper right corner and create the notebook from file

If your Watson Studio instance does not run in Tokyo and you cannot get access to the "*Copy to project*" or "*Download*" functionality, ask your course instructors to provide the notebook in a different way (e.g. via a *.ipynb* file).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
My Watson Studio instance runs in Dallas as I could not open the assignment properly when I set it in Tokyo. But apparently it was doable...
I tried to download it anyway and tried to read it in Jupyter Notebook but it was practically illegible with full of codes.
I will try to contact again the primary instructor directly citing your suggestion.

Comment: Because you told me that it is an HTML data, I tried to click the URL again and this time, somehow, I can see the notebook on a web.
Somehow I could not open it before although I tried many times... 
In any case, it seems to be sorted. Thank you for your suggestion.